# Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression at @Injectable Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngrx

Full Error Message 
Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression. Argument of type 'ClassDecoratorContext' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol | undefined'.

I created a book Module under App Module. Inside that Module I created Service File for Work. When I create a file I got this Error..?

This is My Service File

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn:"root"
})
export class BookService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient){ }
}
```

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R4qZ.png)

This is My book.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BookRoutingModule } from './book-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { bookReducer } from './store/reducer/book.reducer';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BookRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('bookReducer',bookReducer)
  ]
})
export class BookModule { }
```

Comment: This is hard to "debug" do you have a reproduction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If are using VSCode, try to restart your TypeScript Server.

Ctrl+Shift+P > `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`

[It fixed it for me](https://mikebifulco.com/posts/typescript-vscode-error-fix-last-resort#restart-the-ts-server-process)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was in wrong file name: `MyClassts` => `MyClass.ts`